# SQL Server CE missing as required prerequisite in InstallShield LE (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, installshield, prerequisites

I've just enabled InstallShield LE within Visual Studio 2010 and am putting together a setup project. I would like to specify SQL Server CE 4.0 as a required prerequisite such that InstallShield will take care of the complexities of 64 bit vs 32 bit and different OS's without me having to check for registry keys or anything like that.

Why is SQL Server CE not included? It is touted as Microsoft's desktop data solution and InstallShield LE is touted as the replacement for Visual Studio setup projects, so shouldn't it be standard?

I can see a SQL Server CE prq file in InstallShield's Requirements folder (along with numerous others) but it does not show up in Visual Studio. Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just include the required files as content: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: Many thanks Erik. We have previously been distributing CE 3.5 and actually installing it if not present. I see on Microsoft's download page for CE 4.0 it says: "Private deployment of SQL Server Compact further simplified by having all the required managed assemblies, and the x86 and x64 DLLs, including the Visual C++ 2008 runtime libraries (x86 and x64) SP1 in a single private folder in the install location of SQL Server Compact." Good stuff.